# Converting 24hour to 12 hour in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I want to convert my time from 24 hour format to 12 hour format, I tried using this code below to do it but it just does not work what am I missing

what else should I do to make it work. please let me know thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const ScanCounterTime = ({parcelCount}) => {
    function tConvert (time) {
        // Check correct time format and split into components
        time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];
      
        if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
          time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
          time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
          time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
        }
        return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
      }
      
    // useState accepts an initial state and returns two values:
    //1. The current state
    //2. A function that updates the state
    // thats why theres currentTime and setCurrentTime basically it should 
    // show something like 2 - 3 for example 
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(new Date().getHours());

    const updateCurrentTime = () => {
        // this will get the current hour 
        const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
        // this will get the next hour %24 to prevent it from going above it 
        const nextHour = (currentHour + 1) % 24;
        // expression interpolation to store the currentTime and nextHour kinda like pythons format function 
        const hey = tConvert(currentHour);
        const bye = tConvert(nextHour);
        const formattedTime = `${hey} - ${bye}`;
        setCurrentTime(formattedTime);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = 
            setInterval(() => {
                updateCurrentTime()
            },1000); 
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <StyledRectangle>
            <div></div>
            <TimeText>{currentTime}</TimeText>
            </StyledRectangle>
        </div>
    );
};


const StyledRectangle = styled.div`
  width: 134.02px;
  height: 87.17px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 17px rgba(66, 61, 61, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4rem;
`;

const TimeText = styled.span`
  color: white; 
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Aeonik;
  text-align: center;
`;

export default ScanCounterTime;
```

it shows the time in 24 hour but the function I created to convert it does not work.

Comment: Why is this React and not javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Since your data source is a `Date` object, there isn't any "conversion" going on, only "rendering". You can render a `Date` into human-readable string using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), which gives you plenty of options.

```js
const date = new Date();
const hour = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  hour: "numeric",
  hour12: true,
}).format(date);
console.log(hour);
```

Remember: When working with date-time values, always manipulate them in raw value (i.e. unix timestamp, Date object is essentially a wrapper of unix timestamp), only render it to human-readable string (with format and timezone) at the very last step when display to user is needed. In reverse, if you get a formatted date-time string as a data source, always parse it to unix timestamp before any manipulation. Never manipulate date-time as a string.